# Windows 10 reporting 'parameter is incorrect' with USB internal floppy drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, motherboard, floppy

I purchased a Sony internal 3.5 inch floppy drive (34 pin internally FDD interface). I also got a BYTECC BT-146 reader with its FDD connector. The goal was to connect both via one of the cheap 34 pin to usb adapters seen on ebay (https://www.ebay.com/p/1-44mb-3-5-Floppy-Drive-Connector-34-Pin-34p-to-USB-Cable-Adapter-PCB-Board/9020180466?iid=283228590717&chn=ps) and then to the motherboard USB3.0 header via a head to 2 USB port adapter (https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6ZP3KP9751). However, not only does BIOS report boot failure when turned on, but when I force boot to windows 10, windows 10 will not read or write from the drives, reporting 'The parameter is incorrect'. Anyone know how to fix this?

System info: Gigabyte X370 Ultra Gaming Mobo, Ryzen 7 1700, GTX 1080, 64GB RAM, 5 SATA SSDs, 1 NVMe SSD, 1 2TB SATA HDD, Windows 10, both USB2.0 headers occupied, 1 of 2 USB3.0 occupied and the other one for the floppy drives.

Comment: Does the floppy drive work if you connect it externally after boot up?

Comment: @Moab Yes, it does

Comment: Then the bios does not understand the hardware and does not support it, not much you can do.